# Automatically change android profile mode at specific time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, profile, scheduler

How to automatically change profile mode of android phone at specific time in android?

i want to make an application in which the profile mode will change automatically at specific time.

How can i do this??

Comment: You might want to explain what 'the profile mode' is first.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov android default profile modes. like i want to change the profile mode to silent at specific time

Comment: you can change specific setting on an android phone  but there is not general concept of profile in Android....

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar how can i change ring setting at a specific time??

Comment: I have added an answer for setting ringer mode to silent... please have a look..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar but how to do this at specif time????

Comment: what do you mean by specfic time? may be you can use alarm manager for this... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class can be used to set the ringtone.

Use the setRingerMode() method. Following code set the ringtone to silent mode:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Following are the acceptable values for this function:

```
RINGER_MODE_NORMAL, RINGER_MODE_SILENT, or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.
```

Also add the following permission in the manifest file:

```
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

EDIT1:: [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) can be used for execute code at specific time..

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are not built-in Android features, some manufacturers and custom ROMs add them so there's no general API for this.